# OCN client in-memory database

Tags: shareandcharge

I am using the OCN-client locally. I run it in memory, without a database. How does it work? Will it be a problem for me when developing my backoffice service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The in-memory database is good for development (the OCN client will forget connected parties on restart), but when moving to testing and production phases you would want to switch to a persistent database.